# Disabled Checkbox is not showing as checked in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

All,
I have the following bit of PHP to check a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_out_gear[]" id="'.$resultsetgear['gear_checkout_id'].'" value="'.$resultsetgear['gear_checkout_id'].'" class="gear_checkout_checkbox" checked disabled>
```

That code works fine and the checkbox is checked and it is disabled. I'm checking to see if it at least one checkbox is checked by using the following jQuery:

```
var fields = jQuery(".gear_checkout_checkbox").serializeArray(); 
if (fields.length == 0) 
{ 
    jQuery.wl_Alert('Please select a piece of equipment that you\'re checking out!','warning','#no_answers','#workform', {sticky:false}); 
    one_selected = false;
}
```

When that checkbox is checked and disabled the length is always 0. However as soon as I remove the disabled from the code it has a length of at least 1. Any idea how I can get this code to work with a disabled checkbox?

Comment: I don't see any check on if checkbox is checked in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behavior for disabled inputs. From the [jQuery docs on `.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in particular **the element cannot be disabled** and must contain a name attribute.

Just check for the length of the checked boxes using the [`:checked` selector <sup>[jQuery docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), like so:

```
if (jQuery(".gear_checkout_checkbox:checked").length === 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`serializeArray` mimics a form submitting.  When a form is submitted, disabled elements do not get sent.

Use `is(":checked")` instead.

```
jQuery(".gear_checkout_checkbox").is(":checked")
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name
>   attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A disabled checkbox will not be sent, regardless of whether it is checked or not. Therefore it won't be picked up by `serializeArray`. You should check whether the checkbox itself is checked, not if it would be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

A disabled input will not show up because it is disabled. The fact that it is checked is of no consequence.

If you're using jQuery to enable and disable the checkbox, you could use jQuery to also set a value on a hidden input when disabling the checkbox (and to change it again when the checkbox is enabled again). You can then process the hidden input along with the checkboxes and do the correct thing.

Another possibility is to not disable the checkbox at all, but then use CSS changes to indicate it is locked and catch the onchange event to prevent it from being modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` property of jQuery object not the length of the array that is returned by `serializeArray()` method, try the following:

```
if ($(".gear_checkout_checkbox:checked").length === 0) { 
    jQuery.wl_Alert('Please select a piece of equipment that you\'re checking out!','warning','#no_answers','#workform', {sticky:false}); 
    one_selected = false;
}
```